# MDX - icCube - How can i make a "AMCHARTS Combo" Type "Line" To have access to Children

Tags: mdx, iccube

I create a "AMCHARTS Combo" that has like series type a "Line" , i put the navigation strategy "Children" but when i select the Line , it's the same result always the years , it can't be showing the children (Months) , i'm using the time dimension of icCube, i need to pass from years to months

[image]

I hope That you can help me to resolve this problem. Thanks,Marwen

Comment: Are you really using a hierachy that has month level (again check in the MDX IDE, the request is visible in the monitoring tab)

Comment: I try to replace the series type "Line" by "Column" , it work's perfectlly , i click on the column and i can see the Months but when i use the "Line" , it's not working

Comment: You need to add the markers to the line so it's clickable -> https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-and-line-mix/